# Python equivalent of C++ begin() and end() for custom classes

Tags: python, loops, iteration

Say you have a dictionary whose keys are integers. The values are also dictionaries whose keys are strings and whose values are numpy arrays.
Something like:

```
custom = {1: {'a': np.zeros(10), 'b': np.zeros(100)}, 2:{'c': np.zeros(20), 'd': np.zeros(200)}}
```

I've been using this custom data structure quite a lot in the code, and every time I need to iterate over each of the rows in the numpy arrays of this structure, I have to do:

```
for d, delem in custom.items():
    for k, v in delem.items():
        for row in v:
            print(row)
```

Is it possible to encapsulate this behavior in functions *à la* C++ where you can actually implement custom `begin()` and `end()`? Also, the iterator should also have information about the keys in their corresponding dictionaries. I envision something like:

```
for it in custom:
    d, e, row = *it
    # then do something with these
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

custom = {
    1: {'a': np.zeros(10), 'b': np.zeros(100)}, 
    2:{'c': np.zeros(20), 'd': np.zeros(200)}
}

my_gen = (
    (key, subkey, np_array) 
    for (key, a_dict) in custom.items() 
    for subkey, np_array in a_dict.items() 
)

for key, subkey, np_array in my_gen:
    print(key, subkey, np_array)

--output:--
1 b [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
1 a [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
2 d [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.]
2 c [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.]
```

Or, you could reconstitute your data structure into something that is more useful for your purposes:

```
import numpy as np

custom = {
    1: {'a': np.zeros(10), 'b': np.zeros(100)}, 
    2:{'c': np.zeros(20), 'd': np.zeros(200)}
}

#Create a *list* of tuples:
converted_data = [
    (np_array, subkey, key)
    for (key, a_dict) in custom.items() 
    for subkey, np_array in a_dict.items() 
]

for np_array, subkey, key in converted_data:
    print(key, subkey, np_array)
```

Creating a custom iterator:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.max = len(data)
        self.index_pointer = 0

    def __next__(self):
        index = self.index_pointer

        if index < self.max:
            current_val = self.data[index]
            self.index_pointer += 1
            return current_val
        else:
            raise StopIteration


class MyIter:
    def __iter__(self):
        return Dog([1, 2, 3])


for i in MyIter():
    print(i)

--output:--
1
2
3
```

`__iter__()` just needs to return an object that implements a `__next__()` method, so you can combine those two classes like this:

```
class MyIter:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.max = len(data)
        self.index_pointer = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self  #I have a __next__() method, so let's return me!

    def __next__(self):
        index = self.index_pointer

        if index < self.max:
            current_val = self.data[index]
            self.index_pointer += 1
            return current_val
        else:
            raise StopIteration

for i in MyIter([1, 2, 3]):
    print(i)

--output:--
1
2
3
```

A more complex `__next__()` method:

```
import numpy as np

class CustomIter:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.count = 0


    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        count = self.count
        self.count += 1

        if count == 0:  #On first iteration, retun a sum of the keys
            return sum(self.data.keys())

        elif count == 1: #On second iteration, return the subkeys in tuples
            subkeys =  [ 
                a_dict.keys()
                for a_dict in self.data.values()
            ]

            return subkeys

        elif count == 2: #On third iteration, return the count of np arrays
            np_arrays = [
                np_array
                for a_dict in self.data.values()
                for np_array in a_dict.values()
            ]

            return len(np_arrays)

        else:  #Quit after three iterations
            raise StopIteration


custom = {
    1: {'a': np.zeros(10), 'b': np.zeros(100)}, 
    2:{'c': np.zeros(20), 'd': np.zeros(200)}
}

for i in CustomIter(custom):
    print(i)


--output:--
3
[dict_keys(['b', 'a']), dict_keys(['d', 'c'])]
4
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. What is the difference between having `my_gen` in your solution and `custom_dict_iter` in @tdelaney's solution?

Comment: @aarogon, You can define generators directly--without defining a function.  However, you can't rewind a generator, so if you want to get another generator later, I would go with  tdelaney's solution

Comment: @aaragon, You could always wrap a function around the direct generator syntax, e.g. `get_gen(...): return ( (key, subkey, np_array)...`.

Comment: @aaragon, How about converting your data structure into something more friendly?  See the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @aaragon, In case you were interested, and having trouble, I posted an example of creating a custom iterator class at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I see, but how does that work with the custom dictionary type I have? My data structure is a dictionary of dictionaries, so your `MyIter` class wouldn't work because it assumes that the data structure is an array, doesn't it?

Comment: @aaragon, Yes. It's a custom iterator after all. For your data structure, you would need to include the logic for returning the data you want in the __next__() method. Note that you don't need to start at the beginning of your data structure or end at the end, and you can mix and match data--anything you can program can appear in the __next__() method. For simple cases, the direct generator syntax will take care of defining the iterator class for you. If you require more complex calculations in the __next__() method, then you can create your own iterator class (or your own generator function).

Comment: @aaragon, See the more complex example I added.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to do this. `yield` may be the simplest as it does the heavy lifting of building an interator class for you.

```
def custom_dict_iter(custom):
    for d, delem in custom.items():
        for k, v in delem.items():
            for row in v:
                yield d, k, row

for d, k, row in custom_dict_iter(my_custom_dict):
    print(d, k, row)
```

Comment: What you mean is that you would `yield d,k,row` I assume. Still isn't this too verbose? It's much better than what I have though.

Comment: @aaragon You're right. I was fixated on `print(row)`. Fixed.

Comment: @aaragon I don't think its too verbose because you want  to track and return the keys as well as the values. And compare it to overloading the C++ iterator, its pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

Look up the [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) - this is more similar to Java's `Iterable` or C#'s `IEnumerable` than C++'s begin/end. You can define it more easily by defining the `__iter__` method as a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html#generators).

The only thing is, you'd need to make your `custom` have its own class with these methods rather than a plain dictionary, but I assume that's also true in C++.

Comment: Your solution looks interesting. So I guess you mean that I crete a custom class that derives from dictionary, and that overrides the `__iter__` method, right?

Comment: @aaragon You could do that, I guess. I'd probably just have the dictionary as a field.

Comment: @aaragon, You aren't overriding: you just need to define both `__iter__()` and `__next__()` in your custom class.  `__iter__()` has just one line: `return self`.  Inside `__next__()` is where all the action happens. And, inside `__next__()`, you need to `raise StopIteration` when you decide that your iterator has hit the end of the data.   A for-in loop applied to an instance of your custom class will automatically catch a StopIteration exception and terminate.  That's how all for-in loops terminate.

Answer (score 0):

As a more pythonic way you can use a nested list comprehension which performs at C language speed inside the interpreter:

```
>>> [[(i,key,t) for t in value] for i,j in custom.items() for key,value in j.items()]
```

And if you want to get an iterator you can use a generator expression instead of list comprehension.

```
>>> ([(i,key,t) for t in value] for i,j in custom.items() for key,value in j.items())
```

Comment: I think that's close to what @7stud did except that you've built it into an outer list. My solution breaks out the loops... and now I'm curious whether its slower.